# Simple multithreaded socket server does not work (Socket is closed)

Tags: multithreading, sockets

I have a really simple multithreaded server as attached.

When my client calls the server, the server gives below exception:
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
but my code did not close the socket.

The first code segment is my client. The second and third code segments define the server and the way it handles requests. I had another single-threaded client-server and it worked properly. 
Could somebody help take a look?

```
public class SocketClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 900;

    try{
        Socket socket = new Socket(hostname, port);
        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
        writer.println("GET /");
        writer.println();
        writer.flush();

        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.out.println("Server not found: " + ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

```
public class SimpleHTTPServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //create a network socket which can accept connection on certain TCP port
    //create Server which can accept requests
    final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(900);
    System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 900...");
    while(true) {
        try (Socket socket = server.accept()) { //creates socket when new request is received
            System.out.println("received request");
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler(socket); //RequestHandler implements runnable interface, pass this object to create Thread
            Thread thread = new Thread(rh);
            thread.start(); //begins run() method defined in rh
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class RequestHandler implements Runnable {
private Socket socket;
public RequestHandler(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("calling handleRequest");
        handleRequest();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.err.println("Error Closing socket connection");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
private void handleRequest() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("handleRequest called");
    Date today = new Date();
    String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + today;
    System.out.println("1st" + httpResponse);
    socket.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println("2nd" + httpResponse);
    System.out.println("got a new request");
}
```

}

Comment: Probably not the issue here, but usually the first 5000 ports are "reserved". You chose port 900 for your test.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the server to below and it works-

```
public class SimpleHTTPServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //create a network socket which can accept connection on certain TCP port
    //create Server which can accept requests
    final ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(900);
    System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 900...");
    while(true) {
        try { //creates socket when new request is received
            Socket socket = server.accept();
            System.out.println("received request");
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler(socket); //RequestHandler implements runnable interface, pass this object to create Thread
            Thread thread = new Thread(rh);
            thread.start(); //begins run() method defined in rh
//                Date today = new Date();
//                String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + today;
//                socket.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
//                System.out.println("got a new request");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}